# UIApplication Assertion Failure in Xamarin.iOS App

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I was in the middle of developing an update to my Xamarin Forms app, but when I debugged it on my iPhone, it crashed immediately on startup with the following message:

```
Assertion failure in -[UIApplication_runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com/apple.xbs/Source/UIKit/UIKit-3600.5.2/UIApplication.m:3679
```

It was previously working fine, but now I can't run the app on my phone anymore without this crash.  I have rebuilt several times and deployed from different computers, but nothing helps.  How do I fix this issue?

**Edit:**
Before this started occurring, I had made some additions to the code.  Unfortunately, after removing all of my changes, this issue is still plaguing further development.  Any help or resource that might lead me to a solution will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some deep searching, it turns out that I mistakenly removed a part of my `Application`'s constructor that initialized the `MainPage`.  As a result, `MainPage` remained null.  The framework probably tried to call a method or access a property without checking if the reference was null, causing the error.  I'm not sure how long that mistake has been there.

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if you are not quick to launch a view. Avoid calling APIs or other lengthy processes before a page is displayed for the first time. You may do that in parallel but not in the same thread that launches the page.